# VSCode python module debug with nested directories

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import, vscode-debugger, relative-import

I am trying to debug a module in a directory structure as follows

```
cwd
├── project_directory
|   | __init__.py
|   ├──dir1
|      ├── __init__.py
|      ├── module1.py
|   ├──dir2
|      ├── __init__.py
|      ├── module2.py
```

If I run from command line:

`python -m project_directory.dir1.module1`

The code runs just fine, now I would like to configure the `launch.json` file so as to debug the module.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "module": "project_directory.dir1.${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        }
    ]
}
```

Debugging with the above launch file leads to the following error:

`Error while finding module specification for 'dir1.module1' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir1')`

What perplexes me is that if I change my cwd to `project_directory` and edit the `launch.json` file such that

`"module": "dir1.${fileBasenameNoExtension}"`

the debugger starts working. This unfortunately is not a viable solution as I have relative imports and python requires me to be in the parent directory of `project_directory`.

Any ideas on how to get the debugger to work?

And what is the best practice with relative imports so that they cause the least amount of problems?

Comment: The only thing that jumps out at me is that in the error `Error while finding module specification for 'dir1.module1'` it does not say `'project_directory.dir1.module1'` - so somehow it thinks it's on the project_directory already?

Comment: I also thought that to be a bit strange, but, as mentioned, when repeating the same process from `project_directory` as cwd, it is able to run, so might just be a red herring.

Comment: Re last paragraph: I know only one such practice, namely "configure your linters toolchain to prohibit relative import", which works well for almost all projects I know.

Answer (score 0):

Add "env":{ "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"} in your launch.json , to mimic the behavior of -m flag. I use this to solve importing problem when run nested module that require dependency.

Answer reference from [Can't get VSCode/Python debugger to find my project modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290328/cant-get-vscode-python-debugger-to-find-my-project-modules)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "env": { "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"}
        }
    ]
}
```